# what does instance mean in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a class named Starting and my teacher told me to use this ClassName(root) and she called it instance and i dont know what it means and i dont get what she was trying to say either. does anyone know what this means? im guessing its to run whatever is inside the class but i created another class and did the same thing but it wont run. please help, thanks

her code(everything in this class would run properly):

```
class Starting():

if __name__==__main__:
    instance = Starting(root)
```

my code(i get an error, wont let me run):

```
class Starting():
class Question():

if __name__==__main__:
    instance = Starting(root)
    ins = Question(root)
```

Comment: For example, `a = Starting()` then `a` is an ***instance*** of class `Starting`.

Answer (score 0):

An *instance* is just what the word means in English: it is a single occurrence or example of something.

If someone says to you, "would you like a cookie for dessert?", in this case "cookie" is a type of dessert. They aren't asking you about a specific cookie, only about a type or class of dessert. If they instead hand you an actual cookie and say "would you like *this* chocolate chip cookie?", the chocolate chip cookie in your hand is a specific instance of a cookie.

Likewise, in your code `class Starting...` defines a type of object named "Starting", much like "Cookie" defines a type of dessert. When you do `Starting(root)`, you create an instance of that type. That is to say, a specific example of a "Starting". If you did this:

```
instance1 = Starting(root)
instance2 = Starting(root)
```

... then you would have two *instances* of the `Starting` class of objects. Each time you do `Starting(...)` you create a new instance.